# Find out if file is still growing, with delayed actions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to watch over a file and find out when it isn't grwoning anymore.
I execute a external program

```
Process.Start(
    "procdump.exe",
    string.Format(@"-ma {0} Output\{1}_RAW_DUMP.dump",
    processName,
    dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")));
```

and I need to know when this process finished its works.

So I wrote this:

```
private void CheckDumpFile(DateTime startDateTime, IConfigHolder configHolder, List<string> results)
{
    var path = CheckExistensDumpFile(startDateTime);
    const int delayMs = 250;
    if (path == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dumpfile not ready yet, next try in 0.25s, now: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        RetryAction(() => CheckDumpFile(startDateTime, configHolder, results), delayMs);
    }
    else
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        if (fileInfo.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dumpfile has no Length yet, now: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            RetryAction(() => CheckDumpFile(startDateTime, configHolder, results), delayMs);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_lastLength == fileInfo.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dumpfile is " + _lastLength + "bytes, starting analysis, now: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                ReadDumpFile(configHolder, path, results);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dumpfile is still growing, next try in 0.25s, now: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                _lastLength = fileInfo.Length;
                RetryAction(() => CheckDumpFile(startDateTime, configHolder, results), delayMs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this

```
public static void RetryAction(Action action, int delayMs)
{
    new Timer(obj => action(), null, delayMs, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

This works until the file is grwoing to slow and I have a few more call of 'RetryAction'. Than one call isn't coming back.

Do you know what seems to be the problem?
Is there a better solution for my case? I ignored the FilWatcher because someone told me that the FileWatcher is terrible in ne9twork shares.

Comment: One thing's for sure: you shouldn't instantiate a new timer for each call. Use [`Timer.Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change(v=vs.100).aspx) to reset it instead, and of course dispose it when the parent container/control disposes.

Comment: do you just want to test if the file is in use?

Comment: Can you describe what actually happens? If you cannot reproduce it easily, add more trace messages around the code and post the output in your question. Also, an exception might be thrown on a background thread and lost, so you might want to add something like `Application.ThreadException += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());` at the beginning of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem too. I wrote a method which checks the last write time, so even if the file only grows by one byte, it will still be classed as in use.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for completion of writing to a file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fullPath">The full path.</param>
    /// <param name="timeToWait">The time to wait on each attempt.</param>
    /// <param name="retryAttempts">The maximum number of retry attempts.</param>
    /// <param name="safetyBuffer">The safety buffer.</param>
    public static void WaitForFile(string fullPath, TimeSpan timeToWait, int retryAttempts, TimeSpan safetyBuffer)
    {
        var timesSkipped = 0;
        var info = new FileInfo(fullPath);
        var maxWriteTime = DateTime.Now.Add(-safetyBuffer);// no activity for a minute
        while (info.Exists && (info.LastWriteTime > maxWriteTime) && timesSkipped < retryAttempts) {
            Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
            maxWriteTime = DateTime.Now.Add(-safetyBuffer);
            info.Refresh();
            timesSkipped++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Safety buffer" is a bit poor name choice for a timespan IMHO. :-)